# hide private symbols automatically

Tags: c++, makefile, build, linker

I have a C++ project with public and private header files.
To increase encapsulation and decrease symbol clashes in a larger project I would like to export only the minimal set of symbols.

Although we could manually annotate each function with visibility attributes, I'd prefer an approach that does not require changing the source code.

Given the following project structure:

```
LibA
  include
    *.h
  src
    *.h
    *.cpp
```

Is there a way to automatically hide all the symbols that don't appear in `include/*.h` ?

Is there an elegant way of instrumenting the compiler/linker?
Could we automatically generate a version-script ?

Comment: Which compiler/linker are you using?

Comment: Primary clang, gcc and ld.

Answer (score 1):

With gcc and clang, this is as simple as building with `-fvisibility=hidden`. Then you only have to explicitly export the few public symbols you want exposed.

For more details, there's a gcc article on [symbol visibility](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) that you may want to read.

Comment: thanks,  but afaik this would require to change the sourcecode to make symbols public. Do you know any way that does not require changing the source ?

Comment: @Gaetano Sorry, no.

Answer (score 0):

> Could we automatically generate a version-script?

You sure could: run `nm -C *.o | egrep ' [TDBW] '` to get the list of global symbols, then look in `include/*.h` to see which ones should be exported. This will likely be fragile: if you e.g. use macros to generate symbol names, this will probablynot work at all.

It may be worth it to generate the list once, hand-curate it, and then maintain it together with the sources by hand in the revision control system.

If the number of symbols to be exported is relatively small, compiling with `-fvisibility-hidden` and annotating just the public symbols is a much more robust solution.